# Climate on a planet with huge tides

Tags: science-based, planets, climate, solar-system

*Tidea* is a moon with an atmosphere orbiting a giant planet. Due to that, tidal forces on *Tidea* are enormous.

I'm working on trying to understand how would the climate be on *Tidea*.

Relevant things regarding *Tidea*:

- Huge tidal forces.
- High tide lasts 6 days and so do low tide.
- Average 2 AU from the giant planet to Sun.
- No tilting from the Sun.
- Tidal forces warms the *Tidea* to have an average temperature similar to Earth (at least that what [Universe Sandbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universe_Sandbox) says).
- 24h orbital period (which mainly defines day and night)
- Almost 24h rotational period (just enough so tides last 6 days as said before) around the giant planet.
- Has an atmosphere similar to Earth.
- Has a lot of tectonic and volcanic activity (mainly due to the tidal heating)

**How do the huge tidal forces on *Tidea* affect the climate?**
(I understand the tidal forces will also affect the atmosphere and wind currents)

Some have commented I try to cover too much on this question. I'd like to point out that I only intent to ask on a very specific interaction: The change tidal forces have on the climate. I don't ask for a whole description of *Tidea*'s climate.

Comment: The height of tides would approximate a sine wave. Note that on Earth at peaks and troughs we have *slack tide* where the tide is changing direction. The 12 day cycle implies that Tidea has a 12 day orbit, depending on whether your days are planet days or moon days, i.e. rotation relative to the sun. Note that the sun will have a tidal effect. This leads to Spring and Neap tides which you can Google. (Note: 'spring' has nothing to do with the season. It refers to the tides 'springing' very high when the sun and moon are lined up)

Comment: It depends a lot on things you did not say. For example - does this moon even *have* an atmosphere, and thus weather? What is its composition? How does moon geography looks like. Volcanic activity might play a role as well, tidal heating usually implies significant level of that...

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Everything's been added.

Comment: I think the problem is that although, given enough data, an oceanographer could calculate the tides, you are asking specifically about the *weather*. It's not clear how such tides might affect the atmosphere. Perhaps you could explain what makes you think that the height of the water would cause atmospheric 'weather'.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK I understand Tidal Forces affects also the atmosphere. That changes the pressure and wind currents, which highly affect the weather.

Comment: So you're  concerned about tidal effects on the atmosphere as well as the ocean. That's a fascinating question. We need a meteorologist and an oceanographer to answer!  You might like to start here and broaden your search. https://sciencing.com/moon-affects-weather-6529673.html

Comment: Please check your requirement: a tidally locked moon cannot have 6 days tides.

Comment: @L.Dutch it's not tidally locked.

Comment: 24 h rotational period and 24 h orbital period tell me that while it makes a rotation around the planet it also complete a rotation around itself, which is the definition of tidal lock

Comment: @L.Dutch - It can have 6 day tides, (although we still don't know the precise definition of 'day' in this scenario) but such tides are produced entirely by the star they are orbiting. On Earth, the tidal component due to the Sun is considerable. This is a complicated system.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK, the OP states the tides are due to orbiting a giant planet

Comment: I believe that the OP needs to do more research online and then give us the facts and make the question more specific as to what 'weather' means. Is it just wind direction? Are we being asked about rainfall? There is considerable literature on the tidal effects on moons.

Comment: @L.Dutch that's why I added the *almost*. Because it's *almost* tidally locked. Actually the difference is its rotational period is just enough so it has 6 days tides.

Comment: @chasly from UK I concur, more research needed: 2AU orbital radius and 24 hour orbital period - even around a black hole this is pushing, and maybe beyond the limits of angular acceleration  possible, without tearing the planet to pieces with differential gravitational tidal forces.

Comment: @Duckisaduckisaduck The Gas planet is 2AU from sun. *Tidea* is a moon of such planet and the orbital period is around that planet.

Comment: @Masclins My error, think I need new specs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Temperatures (and resulting weather) would largely be influenced by the exposure to sunlight and the tidal forces due to the planets gravity and the moons rotations.
- The height and volume of the tidal waves may significantly influence atmospheric pressure(thus wind) only if they're very large (single or double digit percentages) compared to the moons size and its atmospheric thickness.

**The tidal waves as well as the day-night cycle are determined or additionally influenced by these rotations:**

- The giant planet rotates around the sun.
- The moon rotates around this planet.
- At the same time the moon has its own rotation.

All these rotations will determine the day night cycle (and weather) on the moon (light from the sun reaching a surface portion oriented towards the sun).
Depending on the speed the moon rotates around the planet and the moons own rotation these will shift along the planetary year (one full rotation of the planet around the sun).
Depending on the speed the planet rotates around the sun, the day night cycle on the moon will shift and stretch / contract during the planetary year.

The day-night cycle will vary and may inlcude multiple partial(longer / darker nights) days & nights depending on the moons rotation around its axis and its rotation around the planet.

Similarly the intensity, height and volume of tidal waves will vary as well according to the moons rotation around its axis and around the planet as well as its distance to the sun (may be negligible depending on distance).

***Plotted on graphs or 3D models, both, the tides and the day-night cycle will form
 local and global extrema (maxima and minima).***

This will further complicate your question about the weather impact with smaller and larger cycles.

As has been said, you need scientific advice beyond the scope of this forum if you're looking for calculated, precise enough predictions.

**In conclusion I also should point out that this moon might have extreme tectonic movements resulting in very strong quakes and heavy vulcanic activity.
Sounds like a very inhospitable environment.**

### **Evolution of intelligent life faces many difficulties, constantly on the brink of extinction.**

Same goes for any civilization building settlements on or below the moons surface.